# concatenate before urlencode in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, concatenation, urlencode

I'm new to django and trying to concatenate a variable and string before urlencoding the two.

I already have `#{profile.name|urlencode}` but need something like `#{urlencode('string' + profile.name)}`

Any help is very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate `string` with `profile.name` using [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add) and assign variable to it:

```
{% with name="string"|add:profile.name %}
    {{ name|urlencode  }}
{% endwith %}
```